# How to find the Eigenvector for the particular Eigenvalue?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods

I have found Eigenvector for the Eigenvalue of -1 and 8 for the matrix (Matrix shown in given picture). But when I tried to find the Eigenvector for Eigenvalue 2 then I got myself stuck (shown in the image).

[image]

Comment: What is your question? To find an eigenvector? To find a mistake in your solution? Something else?

Comment: Eigenvector corresponding to 2 is (1,0,0).

Comment: In equation1, I got 2x  = 2x ...... (1)
Do I take it as for any value x is true?

For equation 2 and 3 i figured out y = 0 and z = 0 is the answer.
Eigenvector corresponding to 2 is(x , 0, 0). Can i take any value for x on the basis of equation 1?

Comment: @Arafat_19AK You can take any *non-zero* $x$, and get a basis for the eigenspace.

Comment: @TheoBendit When I take Eigenvalue 8 to find it's corresponding Eigenvector then i got these three equation
2x = 8x, 4y - 5z = 0, 4y - 5z =  0.
.
The Eigenvector for 8 is (1, 5, 4). As I can't take x as 0 and similar reason for y and z. Is this correct or not?

Comment: @Arafat_19AK My comment was about the $\lambda = 2$ case. If you chose $x = 0$, then your "basis" would consist of only the zero vector, and be neither linearly independent, nor would it span the eigenspace. In the case for $\lambda = 8$ (assuming your work is correct), you *must* choose $x = 0$, as the first equation becomes $6x = 0$, i.e. $x = 0$. In order to avoid the $0$ vector, you then must choose $y$ (and hence $z$) to be non-zero. So, just choose $(0, 5, 4)$; the vector you chose does not work with equation one.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you. Now, it's clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

The eigen space given corresponding to an eigen value $\lambda$ is generated by the kernel of the matrix $A-\lambda I_n$ where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of dimension $n=dim(A)$. You can check the wikipedia article for more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspaces,_geometric_multiplicity,_and_the_eigenbasis_for_matrices